# NSStatusItem setTitle is ignored on Yosemite

Tags: c++, objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsstatusitem

I've been working on a new feature for Mac support in Qt. Basically, it's about adding a `NSStatusItem::title()` support. Since Qt is a C++ framework, I am working in scope of ObjC-binding (corresponding method is declared in C++ header and defined in .mm source file).

```
void QCocoaSystemTrayIcon::updateTitle(const QString &title)
{
    NSString *nstitle = title.toNSString();
    [trayItem setTitle: nstitle];
}
```

**Note**: in the code above, toNSString() creates & releases a proper NSString* in place.

Interesting, if you replace actual setting line with

```
[[trayItem view] setToolTip: nsstring];
```

tool tip, in fact, is being changed. It proves that `trayItem` and `nsstring` are proper objects.

I am running IIRC latest OS X Yosemite `10.10.1`

Answer (score 2):

Almost all `NSStatusItem` methods are deprecated in Yosemite because of the new vibrancy features. Nice description here, [NSStatusItem change image for dark tint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24623559/nsstatusitem-change-image-for-dark-tint)

Comment: I am aware that we might keep it as it is for a while to keep legacy. On other hand it doesn't explain why the method takes no effect...

Comment: When compiling for Yosemite SDK those methods literally do nothing because they are not used by the OS. If you target pre-Yosemite you should have no problems (legacy support as you mentioned).

Comment: I was looking into some docs on how to work with NSStatusBarButton, but IIRC there is even no official API reference, what the?

Answer (score 2):

The fact that `[trayItem view]` returns a valid object suggests that you or Qt is setting a custom view.

Once you set a custom view on a status item, setting the title has no effect. (This was true even before these methods were deprecated).

A standard status item (no set custom view) can have its `image` and `title` set and have that be forwarded onto the implicitly created button. This was made more explicit/obvious in 10.10 in that those status item properties were deprecated, and you set the button's properties directly.